# Detect IE11 using ColdFusion

Tags: internet-explorer, coldfusion, internet-explorer-11, browser-detection, cfml

I am able to detect previous versions of Internet Explorer using the code below. However, in IE 11 the User Agent String does not contain the "MSIE" word any more. Is there a way to detect IE 11 by using the same method?

```
<cfif #CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT# CONTAINS "MSIE">
//do something
<cfelse>
//do another thing
</cfif>
```

And this is what I am up to for detecting IE 11, but doesn't work.

```
<cfif #CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT# CONTAINS "MSIE" OR REMatch(#CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT#, "Trident/7.*rv:11")>
</cfif>
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx Stop browser sniffing.

Comment: @KevinB I have to do that in this way. And if you can see i am trying to parse the http_user_agent also but couldnt manage

Comment: Your arguments appear to be out of order for rematch. Additionally, rematch returns an array, so you'll want to test it's length.

Comment: The user agent doesn't contain MSIE precisely to combat what you are trying to do. You haven't stated why you are doing it, but **it's very likely the wrong approach**.

Answer (score 1):

`rematch` accepts two arguments. The first is the regexp, the second is the string you're testing against. Your arguments are out of order.

```
REMatch("Trident/7.*rv:11", CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT)
```

REMatch returns an array, so you're going to want to test the length of the array.

```
arrayLen(REMatch("Trident/7.*rv:11", CGI.HTTP_USER_AGENT)) neq 0
```

**Why are you doing this?**

IE11 is a modern browser, most things that you would normally do with a website or web application will work in IE11 just as well as any other browser.

Comment: I am not writing anything special for the ie versions but rendering style of IE causes a huge problem for my application. It works for all browsers except ie. Considering that i am not very good CF developer, this is the solution i came up with and it works.
Thanks so much

Comment: I haven't had that issue with IE11 (or IE9+ for that matter), sounds like something that would be solved with proper html/css

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if it was a missing/incorrect doctype.

Answer (score 0):

There is an explanation of the new browser string for IE11 here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx

This will help you decide what to put into your expression to detect IE11.